# Google AppEngine + PHP + Google Cloud Datastore: receiving Unauthorized

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a PHP application running at Google App Engine and I want to use the App Engine's datastore in it.

I am using the google-api-php-client, and at the Google Cloud Console I've enabled the Google Cloud Datastore API, and registered a new app, downloading the private certificate.

For the authentication, I'm using the following code (`xxxx` has the real values):

```
const SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME = 'xxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
const KEY_FILE = 'secure/privatekey.p12';

$client = new Google_Client();
$key = file_get_contents ( KEY_FILE );

$client->setAssertionCredentials (
    new Google_AssertionCredentials ( 
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME, 
        array (
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore' 
        ), 
        $key 
    ) 
);

$service = new Google_DatastoreService ( $client );
$datasets = $service->datasets;
```

Whichever operation I use in `$datasets`, like `$datasets->lookup`, I receive an exception stating that the operation is Unauthorized:

```
Uncaught exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message 'Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/datastore/v1beta1/datasets/<my-appengine-id>/lookup: (403) Unauthorized.'
```

What might be wrong?

Comment: What is your project id? and what is the value of XXX?

Comment: The project id is "flytour-intranet" and SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME is 317403747968-mciqlisucn3o49ov1qfpk99rjievkld2@developer.gserviceaccount.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are hitting the following limitation: [service account authorization doesn't work with domain-restricted App Engine application](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/issues/19).

So you can either comment on the issue to get your application whitelisted, keep in mind that it can allow account outside of your domain to auth with your application using OAuth depending on how your application is built.

Comment: First I'll try using the Identity API.

But when I try it, I receive: "Uncaught exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message 'Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/datastore/v1beta1/datasets/flytour-intranet/lookup: (403) Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.".

I've already added the applications account name "flytour-intranet@appspot.gserviceaccount.com" as a member of the Cloud Console project.

Comment: @dudinha-dedalus you should make sure Google Cloud Datastore API is enabled for your project, see https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/activate#google_cloud_datastore_for_accessing_existing_app_engine_datastore_from_other_platform

Comment: yes, it is activated... I even created a new application, activated the "Google Cloud Datastore API", deactivated it and reactivated it again, and it is still not working.

Comment: I don't know if this is relavant, with `AppIdentityService::getAccessToken` and `$client->setScopes` I'm using `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`.

Comment: @dudinha-dedalus since you're querying Google Cloud Datastore from the app itself you have to make sure you enabled Google Cloud Datastore on the Cloud Project associated with this application (and not another project). You can find the link to the project in the following page: https://appengine.google.com/settings?&app_id=s~flytour-intranet

Comment: Can you make sure 'flytour-intranet@appspot.gserviceaccount.com' is added to the team of the associated Cloud Project? Alternatively you can also try to add  me: proppy@google.com to the project and I can figure out what's wrong.

Comment: yes, 'flytour-intranet@appspot.gserviceaccount.com' is added to the team, but not as owner: he is added as editor. I've put you as 'editor'.

Comment: if you want to see the application logs, it is the version 2 at App Engine.

Comment: @dudinha-dedalus it seems that App Identity authentication doesn't work as I expected, I filed a bug on the project: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/issues/28 and update my answer.

Comment: @dudinha-dedalus do you want your application to be whitelisted?

Comment: @dudinha-dedalus whitelisted

Comment: thanks @proppy! :) Just one further comment for the prosperity: with the application whitelisted, you can't use `AppIdentityService::getAccessToken`, you need to register an APP at the Google Cloud console.

Comment: @dudinda-dedalus Yes something else is broken with the identity API, I will file a bug on the github project.